# A minimum spanning tree that minimizes the degree of a specific node

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

How can we find the minimum spanning tree that minimizes the degree of a node `v` (among all minimum spanning trees)?

Would modifying Kruskal algorithm such that if there are several edges with the same weight we choose the one that doesn't touch `v` solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in part, modifiying Kruskal's algorithm as sketched in the question does not solve the problem. Consider the graph `G=(V,E,w)` where

```
V = {1,2,3},
E = {{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,1}},
w({1,2}) = 1,
w({1,3}) = 1,
w({2,3}) = 2
```

and `1` is the node of which the degree in the minimum spanning tree is to be minimized. Then, the edge set

```
S1={{1,2},{1,3}}
```

constitutes a minimum spanning tree of weight `2`. However, the modified version of Kruskal's algorithm would without loss of generality select edge `{1,2}` which would result in `{1,3}` being forbidden, such that `{2,3}` is selected. In total, in the selected edge set

```
S2={{1,2},{2,3}}
```

the node `1` has lesser degree than in `S2`, but the total weight of `S2` is `3`, which means that it does not constitute a minimum spanning tree.

Furthermore, note that the degree of the node `v` which is to be minimized has to be at least `3` to have the possibility of more than one neighbourhood of `v` in minimum spanning trees.

In an exhaustive search, select any possible neighbourhood of `v`. As `v` has at most `n` neighbors, there are at most `2^n` such neighbourhoods. Using the algorithm by Prim, expand each of these to a spanning tree which is cost-minimal with respect to containing the selected neighborhood of `v`; in all these solutions which are cost-minimal, select one in which the degree of `v` is minimized. However, the approach does not yield a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: I think there's some error in the definition of G?  you didn't define node 4 but include an edge {3,4}, and didn't specify its weight.